# Strange behavior when I try to hide the Card styled sidebar

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have created a sidebar that lists the popular products in a card-style box. But the issue is when I try to hide the card, the image inside the card do not hide. Why is this strange behavior occurring? Do you have any solution? If yes, please explain it also.
See the snippet for better understanding.

```js
function toggleProduct(){ document.getElementById("popular-product").classList.toggle("hideproduct");}
```

```css
#popular-product.hideproduct{
 width:0;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition:width 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
#popular-product{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 height:100%;
 width:316px;
 background-color:rgb(236, 236, 236);
 background-color:rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.31);
 padding-top:4px;
 padding-bottom:4px;
 padding-left:8px;
 padding-right:8px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition:width 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
#popular-product .popular-product-box{
 margin:8px 0px;
 padding:2px 1px;
 height:168px;
}
#popular-product .popular-product-box:first-child{
 margin:0px;
}
#popular-product .popular-product-box .inner-content{
 border-radius:4px;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 box-shadow:0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background-color:#ffffff;
 height:166px;
 text-align:center;
}
.content-img{
 height:104px;
 width:86px;
}
.popular-product-box .inner-content span{
 margin-top:0px;
 font-size:16px;
}

span.off-circle{
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius:100% 100%;
 -moz-border-radius:100% 100%; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
 background-color: rgb(210, 14, 14);
    background-color: rgba(210, 14, 14, 0.78);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/titatoggle/1.2.14/titatoggle-dist-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .checkbox-slider--b input+span:after {
    top: -7px;
   } 
</style>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="s-c-box">
    <div class="row text-center">
     <div class="checkbox checkbox-slider--b checkbox-slider-md">
      <label>
       <input type="checkbox" checked id="product-switch" onChange="toggleProduct();"/><span style="position:relative;">Show/Hide</span>
      </label>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div>

<div id="popular-product">
 <div class="popular-product-box">
   <div class="inner-content">
    <span class="off-circle">70%<small>off</small></span>
    <img src="http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/dr%C3%B6na-box-blue__0162140_pe317380_s4.jpg" alt="poplular product" class="content-img"/>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because .hideproduct only changes the width of the container, the height is set to 100% which will show the image within the container. You can set .hideproduct to also set the height to 0, which will fix the issue but may not be the behavior you want.

A better solution would be to set .hideproduct to modify the margin, moving the container out of the viewport.

```js
function toggleProduct(){ document.getElementById("popular-product").classList.toggle("hideproduct");}
```

```css
#popular-product.hideproduct{
 margin:0 0 0 -316px;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:margin 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition:margin 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
#popular-product{
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 height:100%;
 width:316px;
 background-color:rgb(236, 236, 236);
 background-color:rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.31);
 padding-top:4px;
 padding-bottom:4px;
 padding-left:8px;
 padding-right:8px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:width 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition:width 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
#popular-product .popular-product-box{
 margin:8px 0px;
 padding:2px 1px;
 height:168px;
}
#popular-product .popular-product-box:first-child{
 margin:0px;
}
#popular-product .popular-product-box .inner-content{
 border-radius:4px;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 box-shadow:0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background-color:#ffffff;
 height:166px;
 text-align:center;
}
.content-img{
 height:104px;
 width:86px;
}
.popular-product-box .inner-content span{
 margin-top:0px;
 font-size:16px;
}

span.off-circle{
    font-size: 13px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius:100% 100%;
 -moz-border-radius:100% 100%; 
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
 background-color: rgb(210, 14, 14);
    background-color: rgba(210, 14, 14, 0.78);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/titatoggle/1.2.14/titatoggle-dist-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .checkbox-slider--b input+span:after {
    top: -7px;
   } 
</style>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12" id="s-c-box">
    <div class="row text-center">
     <div class="checkbox checkbox-slider--b checkbox-slider-md">
      <label>
       <input type="checkbox" checked id="product-switch" onChange="toggleProduct();"/><span style="position:relative;">Show/Hide</span>
      </label>
     </div> 
    </div>
   </div>

<div id="popular-product">
 <div class="popular-product-box">
   <div class="inner-content">
    <span class="off-circle">70%<small>off</small></span>
    <img src="http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/dr%C3%B6na-box-blue__0162140_pe317380_s4.jpg" alt="poplular product" class="content-img"/>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yesterday I was also trying this with margin and It was working correctly but I didn't understand why with margin?

Answer (score 1):

Add an id attribute to your img tag  Like this:

```
    <img id="content-img-1" src="http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/images/products/dr%C3%B6na-box-blue__0162140_pe317380_s4.jpg" alt="poplular product" class="content-img"
   />
```

then add a hideimage class to your css

```
.hideimage{
    display: none;
}
```

finally change the toggleProduct() function to

```
function toggleProduct(){ 
    document.getElementById("popular-product").classList.toggle("hideproduct");
    document.getElementById("content-img-1").classList.toggle("hideimage");
    }
```

That should do it.

But if you have more than one images/cards then it is preferable to use `getElementsByClassName` than `getElementById`

Comment: Thanks, but It would not work with all other elements inside the card and for this I don't require javascript. I can also achieve this using CSS only. But setting margin is the better option. However, I am gratefull that you try to give your best answer.